# Android Irrlicht Bullet random memory management crash

Tags: android, memory, physics, bullet, irrlicht

I've been struggling to fix some final bugs in our game. The game uses Android port of Irrlicht and Bullet physics.

The same code was tried on OS X and Windows without any problem. However, when we ported the code to Android NDK and now get random crashes. Most of the crashes are in `libc.so` which is probably kinda nullpointerexception. We do not use `scenenode->remove()` in our code, instead `smgr->addToDeletionQueue`.

The crash is so random that it occurs in the following statements.

1. `libc.so`
2. `smgr->drawall()`
3. `stepsimulation` in bullet.

The error occurs 90% of the time when we unload a level and load next level or reload a level. We first doubted on compiler and used stlport. Should boost library help?

I am sure, the information I've provided is very little to guess the problem. But since the same game code worked fine on other platforms, I just wanted to clear my doubts on compiler related differences.

A simple `malloc` and then `delete` in android ndk crashes at delete. So I wanted to have a better understanding if what we are struggling to fix is a stupid problem related to compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with this problem for a couple of weeks, I finally found the source of the problem.

I initiallized a char array like this

```
char data = new char[10];
```

and then considered filling the last char as usual with '\0'

```
data[10] = '\0';
```

which throw a nullpointer exception.

I was able to pin point this problem when I run the same code in Windows. Even on windows the problem didn't show-up when running with debugger attached. however, when I run the app by opening the exe directly it crashed. So I had to use the program "Application Verifier" to pin point the problem.